# Could a Legendre transform be equivalent to evaluation in a retarded time?

Tags: partial-derivative, change-of-variable, legendre-transformation

We have the following function:

$$U = U(r(t), p(t)) = (α/r)·\sqrt{1 - p^2/c^2}$$

being $α$ and $c$ positive constants, $t$ a real variable $0$ or positive, and $p = dr/dt$.

I would like to show that if we define

$t'= t – r(t)/c$

it is true that

$U' = U - p·(∂U/∂p)$

where the prime ' stands for evaluated at $t'$.

The origin of the problem is electrodynamics.
I try to show that the Legendre transform of the electrodynamic potential is equivalent to a retarded potential evaluated at instant $t'$.

I have tried to prove it from:

$\Delta U=\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial r} \right)\cdot \Delta r+\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial p} \right)\cdot \Delta p$

being

$\Delta U={U}'-U$,
$\Delta r={r}'-r$,
$\Delta p={p}'-p$
and $p={dr}/{dt}\;$

Then

${U}'=U+\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial r} \right)\cdot \Delta r+\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial p} \right)\cdot {p}'-\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial p} \right)\cdot p$

In order to prove my equation, then

$0=\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial r} \right)\cdot \Delta r+\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial p} \right)\cdot {p}'$

We can assume that (for $\Delta t\ll 0$, and taken into account that ${t}'=t-r(t)/c$

$\Delta r=p\cdot \Delta t=p\cdot \left( {-r}/{c}\; \right)$

And $p’$ should be

${p}'=c\cdot \left( 1-\frac{{{p}^{2}}}{{{c}^{2}}} \right)$

But I can't think of how to prove the latter.
I think the approach I have followed is inappropriate. That is why I am asking for help.

Comment: What have you tried and what has this to do with a Legendre transform?

Comment: The origin of the problem is electrodynamics. 
I try to show that the Legendre transform of the electrodynamic potential is equivalent to a retarded potential evaluated at instant t'.
I have tried to prove it from:
∆U = (∂U/∂r)·∆r + (∂U/∂p)·∆p
being
∆U = U’ - U,  ∆r = r’ - r,  ∆p = p’ - p  and  p = dr/dt
Then
U’ = U + (∂U/∂r)·∆r + (∂U/∂p)·p’ - (∂U/∂p)·p
to prove then
(∂U/∂r)·∆r + (∂U/∂p)·p’ = 0
We can assume that (for ∆t <<0, and taken into account that t’ = t - r/c)
∆r = p· ∆t = p·(-r/c)
And p’ should be
p’ = c· (1 – p^2/c^2)
But I can't think of how to prove the latter.

Comment: Raskolnikov's edit shows how to type formulas in mathjax. If you edit the question to put that comment of yours in I will take a closer look.

Comment: For Legendre transform and its connections with Physics, see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.1147).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the comments you look at the
time transformation $$t'=t-r(t)/c$$ and evaluate
$U(r(t),p(t))$ at $t=t'$ which gives
$$\tag{A}
U\Big(r(t'),p(t')\Big)=U\Big(r\big(t-r(t)/c\big),p\big(t-r(t)/c\big)\Big)\,.
$$
(I do not think we have to denote this by $U'\,.$) Then you ask if (A) is of the form
$$\tag{B}
U\Big(r(t),p(t)\Big)-p(t)\frac{\partial U}{\partial p}\Big(r(t),p(t)\Big)\,.
$$
I find this very unlikely. Taking the $t$ derivative of (A) and (B) leads
to a nonlinear system of first order ODEs for $r(t)$ and $p(t)\,.$ Only when these functions satisfy that system we have equality of (A) and (B).

***Some background on Legendre transforms:***

For simplicity I assume $r>0$ and $p=\dot r>0\,.$ From
$$
\frac{\partial U}{\partial p}=\frac{\alpha}{rc^2}\frac{-p}{\sqrt{1-\frac{p^2}{c^2}}}=\frac{-\alpha}{rc^2\sqrt{\frac{1}{p^2}-\frac{1}{c^2}}}\,,\quad \frac{\partial^2U}{\partial p^2}=\frac{\alpha}{2rc^2}\frac{-2p^{-3}}{\Big(\frac{1}{p^2}-\frac{1}{c^2}\Big)^{3/2}}
$$
it follows that $U$ is strictly concave in $p\,.$ This allows to express the Legendre transform of $U$ as a nice function of $\partial U/\partial p\,.$ The convex
conjugate of $p\mapsto U(r,p)$ is the function
$$\tag{1}
U^*(r,q)=\sup_{p>0}\{qp-U(r,p)\}
$$
which is also called Fenchel-Legendre transform. Since $p\mapsto U(r,p)$
is strictly concave the supremum in (1) is attained for the unique $p$ that satisfies
$$\tag{2}
q=\frac{\partial U}{\partial p}(r,p)\,.
$$
This allows to write
$$\tag{3}
U^*(r,q)=qp-U(r,p)\,.
$$
Note that

- $p$ in (3) is a function of $q\,.$
- Therefore, $U^*$ is ***not*** a function of $p$ but instead of the conjugate variable $q=\frac{\partial U}{\partial p}\,.$
- In the physics literature a Legendre transform (3)  is often written quite sloppily as
  $$\tag{4}
  U^*=p\frac{\partial U}{\partial p}-U\,.
  $$
  This ignores the fact that $U^*$ is not a function of $p\,$.
  For further details, see [Zia et.al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.1147).
- Up to a minus sign, your $U'$ (my (B)) is the sloppy $U^*$ from (4) but this would be a Legendre transform and not a time transform.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.
I don't fully understand the meaning of the equality:

${U}'\left( {r}'({t}'(t)),{p}'({t}'(t)) \right)=U\left( r(t),p(r) \right)$

Do you mean that $U$ evaluated at $t'$ is equal to $U$ evaluated at $t$?

Comment: I think there may be some confusion with the notation. For me, 
${U}'=U\left( r(t={t}'),p(t={t}') \right)$ 
and 
$U=U\left( r(t),p(t) \right)$ 
therefore, in general, $U$ and $U'$ would only be equal when $t = t'$.

Comment: Thank you very much, Kurt G., for addressing my comments by modifying your answer.
I too think it is highly unlikely that equality is satisfied for any $U$. However, my purpose is more modest and I would only like to show that it is valid with a potential $U$ of the form
$U=\frac{\alpha }{r}\cdot \sqrt{1-\frac{{{p}^{2}}}{{{c}^{2}}}}$ 
.I would equally well worth a demonstration that even in that case it is not satisfied (although this would be very disappointing to me).